# Type mismatch error in VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

Hey guys i am trying to search a column of dates and count how many fall between two dates. I get an error Type mismatch when i run it.

```
Dim iVal As Integer
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs("Incident_stats!k:k", ">=" & B1, "Incident_stats!k:k", "<=" & B2)
Range("D1").Value = iVal
```

Comment: Nope still same error

Answer (score 2):

`Countifs` requires Range objects, not address strings:

```
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("Incident_stats!k:k"), ">=" & Range("B1"), Range("Incident_stats!k:k"), "<=" & Range("B2"))
```

I assumed the B1 and B2 were cells too, rather than variables.